# Kotlin: Map collection to json array with Jackson

Tags: json, spring-mvc, kotlin, jackson

New to Kotlin, I am trying to set up a web server with kotlin spring webserver template

Here I want to convert kotlin collection as array of JSON objects

Sample endpoint named `test`

```
@PostMapping(value = [ "/test"],produces = [ "application/json" ],headers = [ "Content-Type=application/json" ])
    fun test(@RequestBody request:IOUDATA): ResponseEntity<String>{

      //need this as JSON array of object
      val numbersMap = mapOf("key1" to 1, "key2" to 2, "key3" to 3, "key4" to 1)

      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("${numbersMap}");

}
```

Expected result

```
 {
   result:[
     {"key1":1},{"key2":2}...
    ]
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your controller is declared to return a `String` and you don't let Jackson create it, but you rather rely on the default `toString` implementation (that gets called by Kotlin's string interpolation mechanism).

In order to have Jackson serialise the object you have 2 different ways:

1. Let the controller return a `ResponseEntity<String>` and manually serialise your object to a String:

   ```
   @RestController
   class MyController(private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper) {

       @PostMapping(value = ["/test"], produces = ["application/json"], headers = ["Content-Type=application/json"])
       fun test(@RequestBody request: MyInputData): ResponseEntity<String> {

           val numbersMap = mapOf(
               "result" to listOf(
                   mapOf("key1" to 1),
                   mapOf("key2" to 2),
                   mapOf("key3" to 3),
                   mapOf("key4" to 1)
               )
           )
           val mySerialisedString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(numbersMap)

           return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(mySerialisedString) // Jackson will serialize it automatically

       }
   }
   ```

   Note in this case you need to get an instance of `ObjectMapper` (autowired by Spring).
2. Create your own result object that will get serialised automatically by Jackson (which will be called by Spring under the hood):

   ```
   @RestController
   class MyController {

       @PostMapping(value = ["/test"], produces = ["application/json"], headers = ["Content-Type=application/json"])
       fun test(@RequestBody request: MyInputData): ResponseEntity<MyOutputData> {

           val numbersMap = listOf(mapOf("key1" to 1), mapOf("key2" to 2), mapOf("key3" to 3), mapOf("key4" to 1))

           val myOutputData = MyOutputData(numbersMap)
           return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(myOutputData) // Jackson will serialize it automatically

       }
   }

   class MyOutputData(val result: List<Map<String, Int>>)
   ```

Both cases return the following JSON String when called:

```
{
    "result": [
    {
        "key1": 1
    },
    {
        "key2": 2
    },
    {
        "key3": 3
    },
    {
        "key4": 1
    }
    ]
}
```